# How to extract time from date string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, javascript-objects

How to extract time fro a date string in javascript?
For reference :
date is 2020-03-11T10:00:00
and need to extract 10:00:00

```
using :let d = new date().toISOString().replace(/^[^:]*([0-2]\d:[0-5]\d).*$/, "$1");
console.log(d);
```

which returns `10:00`

Comment: Why regex? Why not `.split("T")` or `.slice()`, or ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the wanted part.

```js
var iso = '2020-03-11T10:00:00',
    time = iso.slice(11, 19);

console.log(time);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-03-11T10:00:00').toLocaleTimeString());
```